# useMemo return type is wrong, but tsc will not show error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```js
const labelTypeMap = useMemo<Record<'between' | 'inner', string>>(
  () => ({
    between: formatMessage({ id: 'addGroup' }),
    inner: '+',
    aaa: 123, // no error here
  }),
  []
);
```

As the code, there's no error on `aaa`, even it doesn't match the return type of useMemo.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that still demonstrates the issue:

```
const labelTypeMap: Record<"between" | "inner", string> = (() => ({
    between: "xxx",
    inner: "+",
    aaa: 123,
}))();
```

The issue is that Typescript, in general, allows extra properties on objects. After all, an object with extra properties *is* compatible (in an object-oriented sense) with the base type. Surprises only happen when you use dynamic introspection features like `Object.keys` and similar.

The only exception to this flexibility is when you try to assign an object literal directly:

```
const labelTypeMap: Record<"between" | "inner", string> = {
    between: "xxx",
    inner: "+",
    aaa: 123, // Error as expected
};
```

Now it will complain as expected.

So one possible solution to your problem is this:

```
const labelTypeMap = useMemo(() => {
    const result: Record<"between" | "inner", string> = {
        between: "xxx",
        inner: "+",
        aaa: 123, // Error as expected
    };

    return result;
}, []);
```

This also works:

```
const labelTypeMap = useMemo(
    (): Record<"between" | "inner", string> => ({
        between: "xxx",
        inner: "+",
        aaa: 123, // Error as expected
    }),
    [],
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is indeed what I'm looking for!

Comment: @takeItIzzy please don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar situation, where I found typescript does not infer the type as expected.

```
const cmsConfig = {
   adsadasdasdas: 1234,
};


<CMSConfigProvider value={cmsConfig}>

export const CMSConfigProvider: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<{ value: ICMSConfig }>> = ({ children, value })
export interface ICMSConfig {
   expected: number;
}
```

shouldnt ts error if it assigns value = {cmsConfig} ?