# Why don't I receive "property does not exist on X" on objects returned by lambdas?

Tags: typescript

I normally receive a compile error when I accidentally include excess properties on an object.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be receiving the same error when including excess properties on objects returned by lambdas.

Why is this?

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: boolean;
}

const foo1: () => Foo = () => {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // No error, why?
  };
};

const foo2 = (): Foo => {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // Error! GOOD!
  };
};

function foo3(): Foo {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // Error! GOOD!
  };
}
```

---

TypeScript Version 4.1.2

Comment: This may be a TypeScript bug.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=excess+property+checks+typescript+site:stackoverflow.com Maybe it has to do with the *parameter* having to be exact, but the return value not having to be exact

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added `foo3` to indicate this is not the issue here

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXEZgDYRwgDcuAvrrjAK4gJjDojIyYAggAoAlOQxY8BAgl4BnMMkgBbAA7IAvDiIlyYKGwgAaZAHcAFnEgA3aPsMRGDGcigQwbKH1VqGzVg4uHj4BdAAhMQlMHHwZd09vWNdXYjJlR2M4lOULYHl82mgodHSDIyzXZkYgA for a similar example.  It might be arcane-but-known behaviour.

Comment: I'd love a flag to disable it if so :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [lambda return types being covariant](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-compatibility#return-type):

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: boolean;
}
interface Bar {
  Bar: boolean;
}

type Foo1 = () => Foo;
type Foo2 = () => Foo & Bar;

const foo1: Foo1 = (null as any) as Foo2; // NO ERROR (permitted by covariance)
const foo2: Foo2 = (null as any) as Foo1; // ERROR
```

In the OP's question, `foo1` is a variable of type `() => Foo`, but assigned into it is an object of type `() => Foo & { iShouldNotBeHere: boolean }`, which is allowed through lambda type variance, as explained above.

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: boolean;
}

const foo1: () => Foo = () => {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // No error, why?
  };
};

const foo2 = (): Foo => {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // Error! GOOD!
  };
};
```

Which is equivalent to writing:

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: boolean;
}
interface Bar {
  iShouldNotBeHere: boolean;
}

const foo1: () => Foo = (): Foo & Bar => { // Upcasting of lambda allowed by covariance
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // No error.
  };
};

const foo2 = (): Foo => {
  return {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // Error.
  };
};
```

**UPDATE:**

The following ESLint rule will enforce return types on lambdas that return object literals, which will overcome this issue for you:

https://github.com/upload-io/eslint-plugin-return-types-object-literals

Comment: I solved this by using the ESlint rule `explicit-function-return-type` with `allowExpressions: false` and `allowTypedFunctionExpressions: false` to enforce explicit return types in all lambda function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)
Literal objects are treated in different way than references

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

See next example, it compiles:

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: boolean;
}

function foo1(f: (_: () => Foo) => Foo): void {
  f(() => ({
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true // No error! Why is this happening?
  }));
}

function foo2(f: (_: Foo) => Foo): void {
  const result = {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true 
  }
  f(result);
}

function foo3(): Foo {
  const result = {
    bar: false,
    iShouldNotBeHere: true
  };
  return result
}
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding your first example, see quote from the docs:

> or passing them as arguments

Comment: I don't think this answers why the checks are forgone in lambdas. The docs state that excess checks are performed when "assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments". It doesn't mention "returned from a lambda", sure, but neither does it mention "returned from a function", yet the latter returns an error. Only the former does not.

Answer (score 0):

captain-yossarian is right in their answer, and I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793710/usememo-return-type-is-wrong-but-tsc-will-not-show-error) today. But I don't think either of us explained why.

The excess property check only gives an error when an object literal with an an unknown property is given **directly** instead of an expected type. **Directly** is the key. So the following gives an error:

```
interface MyType {
    myProp: string;
}

const myVar: MyType = {
    myProp: "myProp value",
    extra: "Not cool :/", // ERROR HERE
}
```

And so does the following:

```
interface MyType {
    myProp: string;
}

const myFunc = (): MyType => ({
    myProp: "myProp value",
    extra: "Not cool :/", // ERROR HERE
});
```

But not the following:

```
interface MyType {
    myProp: string;
}

type MyFuncType = () => MyType;

const myFunc: MyFuncType = () => ({
    myProp: "myProp value",
    extra: "Not cool :/", // LOOK, NO ERROR!
});
```

Why? In the last example `myFunc` is a function that returns an object type compatible with the expected `MyType`. So the function type is compatible even if the returned object type is not. That's beacuase, apparently, excess property check is only done for immediate assignments (or returns).

Comment: I think it's actually a case of return types on lambda types (e.g. `Func<IN1, IN2, OUT>`) being covariant by default, rather than invariant.